Prep and clean DNS records for serving protonmail
I pay for a domain name through a web hosting company (Ionos) and would like clean out all the cruft DNS entries that come with the domain name. I assume some of these records are in place to serve the awful "This website is brand new!" spam placeholder site and to pre-establish some links to their email backend; I see some MX records.
I would like to follow ProtonMail's instructions to point my domain to their webmail backend per these instructions.
To prepare for that, I would like a minimal, clean set of DNS records. See below. Please recommend which of these I can delete and which are necessary. Again, I don't pay for any service other than the domain, I just want whatever is necessary to be in good standing with the upstream systems to not reject incoming lookups.



TYPE
HOST NAME
VALUE
SERVICE
ACTIONS




CNAME
_domainconnect
_domainconnect.1and1.com
Domain Connect



MX
@
mx00.ionos.com
Mail



MX
@
mx01.ionos.com
Mail



CNAME
s1-ionos._domainkey
s1.dkim.ionos.com
Mail



CNAME
s2-ionos._domainkey
s2.dkim.ionos.com
Mail



CNAME
_______._domainkey
_____.dkim.ionos.com
Mail



CNAME
autodiscover
adsredir.ionos.info
Mail



TXT
@
"v=spf1 include:_spf-us.ionos.com ~all"
SPF



A
@
XX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Webhosting



AAAA
@
MAC address
Webhosting



A
www
XX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Webhosting



AAAA
www
MAC address
Webhosting





For reference, IPv6 addresses in your AAAA records are not MAC addresses – the only similarity is that both are written in hexadecimal digits...
